# First steps to programming an event Calendar, where to start?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, calendar

I am teaching myself some core web technologies, mainly javascript php and mysql. I would like to create an event calendar that ties these 3 together.

I am thinking that I will draw the calendar in javascript, then use php to add events from a mysql database. Right now the first step in my mind is to create a function that will draw the calendar, and then I will call it with document.write. Is this the most logical method to go about this?

Comment: Well I certainly wouldn't use `document.write`

Comment: I would draw the calendar with html and css. Then have AJAX handle adding new events -- as well have simple GET/POST as a fallback (if you want your calendar to work without JavaScript).

Comment: document.onload then? I'd like to add the html and css using javascript DOM methods and properties, the main reason why I am creating the calendar is for practice so although it would be easier to just draw it with html/css I would like to stick with js

Comment: I think this is better suited for [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan/write requirements for the calendar. What it will do and so forth

Start with design first. Using just HTML  CSS JAVASCRIPT

Then plan database DB_SCHEMA as SteamFire said

The implement using php

Just a broad over view

Comment: I am trying to create the table and add the days of the week, but this code i wrote is not working for me..sorry still new with this I did some codeacademy tuts and read up on w3c but thats it, heres the code in question:

Answer (score 7):

Here's a start for you: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/JLPfJ/)

Click around on the dates and you'll see the `selected` style change.

[image: example]

**Note** this depends on [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - *the* essential lib for working with dates/times in JavaScript

**Boilerplate HTML**

```html
<ul id="calendar">
    <li><span>Sun</span></li>
    <li><span>Mon</span></li>
    <li><span>Tue</span></li>
    <li><span>Wed</span></li>
    <li><span>Thu</span></li>
    <li><span>Fri</span></li>
    <li><span>Sat</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Some CSS**

```css
#calendar {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#calendar li {
    float: left;
    width: 13%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}

#calendar li span {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#calendar li.selected span {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#calendar li.today span {
    background-color: #33f;
    color: white;
}

#calendar li.offset-0 { margin-left: 0%; }
#calendar li.offset-1 { margin-left: 14%; }
#calendar li.offset-2 { margin-left: 28%; }
#calendar li.offset-3 { margin-left: 42%; }
#calendar li.offset-4 { margin-left: 56%; }
#calendar li.offset-5 { margin-left: 70%; }
#calendar li.offset-6 { margin-left: 84%; }
```

**A little bit of JavaScript**

```js
function Calendar(elem, date) {

    // private data variables
    var today = moment(date),
        first = moment(today).date(1);

    // private api
    function createDay(n) {
        var li = document.createElement("li"),
            span = document.createElement("span");

        span.innerHTML = n;
        li.appendChild(span);

        return li;
    }

    function addDay(n) {
        var li = createDay(n);
        if (n === 1) {
            li.classList.add("offset-" + first.day());
        }
        if (n === today.date()) {
            li.classList.add("today");
        }
        elem.appendChild(li);
    }

    function deselect(li) {
        if (!li) return;
        li.classList.remove("selected");
    }

    function select(li) {
        deselect(elem.querySelector(".selected"));
        li.classList.add("selected");
    }

    function onClick(event) {
        select(event.srcElement.parentNode);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // init
    for (var i=1, days = today.daysInMonth(); i<=days; i++) {
        addDay(i);
    }

    // event listeners
    elem.addEventListener("click", onClick);

}
```

You can use `Calendar` like this

```
function init() {
  var cal = document.getElementById("calendar"),
      today = new Date;

  new Calendar(cal, today);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

Comment: that library looks infinitely useful, thanks!

Comment: @user3376521, just for the record, the code I wrote here for you is not included in the momentjs lib; it's just using momentjs in some parts.

Comment: naomik what do the two arguments in the calendar function do? I was having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the code so thats why I tried to go solo

Comment: @user3376521, `cal` is the HTMLElement that you want to "attach" the JavaScript to. `today` is just today's date, this is what get's a special class to highlight a cell in the calendar output. Really, you set it up however you want though. This code is by no means, complete in terms of all of the features you want, but it's pretty good starting code to show you how to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Is there any way you could add comments to your code, to make it easier for me to put the pieces together to paint the entire picture? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: I'm having trouble running the code you provided in my IDE, the only thing I can think of that my be causing a problem is moment.js isn't being used by the script. I have a script tag with the src pointing to the moment.js script on their website in my head tag in the html page. when I run the code it displays the boilerplate HTML of the days of the week, but nothing else

Comment: @user3376521, I added a `DOMContentLoaded` listener that waits for the DOM to load before initializing the calendar. See the last bit of code in my post.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. I am alternating between reading the html version of eloquent javascript and javascript code-academy tuts, I still have some work to do as far as understanding how to actually write a program, understanding the syntax is the easy part, thinking like a programmer is the hard

Answer (score 1):

No, I advise you to start with thinking about the Database. Make a schema and create the database. Then, think about all the services that you will use and implement them (Show/Add/Edit/Delete events/users...).
Test your services, when all your services are great implemented. Code your web app.

1. Database
2. Services (php)
3. Web app

That's my opinion but I think it's a great order.