# Adding a date to the top of an event calendar, using a new table row

Tags: javascript

I want to display the current month, year, and day at the top of an event calendar that I am creating. I am having a problem displaying it when I run the script however.

Here is the code in question:

```
// creates a table row, assigns a new date to a variable, then gets the current date
date = document.createElement("tr"),
x = new Date(month, day, year),
timestamp = x.getDate(),

// adds the table row to the table and changes its content to show the date
table.appendChild(date);
date.innerHTML(timestamp);
```

and here is the full code:

```
window.onload = drawcalendar;


function drawcalendar() {
var daysofweek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",   "Saturday"],
    date = document.createElement("tr"),
    x = new Date(month, day, year),
    timestamp = x.getDate(),
    table = document.createElement("table"),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    len = daysofweek.length,
    cell;


table.appendChild(row);
table.appendChild(date);
date.innerHTML(timestamp);

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = daysofweek[i];
}

  document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).appendChild(table);

}
```

Comment: Where is this code being called? What is `table`?

Comment: /me [feels like she taught you nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929053/first-steps-to-programming-an-event-calendar-where-to-start/22929708#22929708). Sincerely disappoint.

Comment: `date.innerHTML = timestamp;` And read about what `getDate` does exactly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Comment: Furthermore, a calendar is arguably **not** a table. It's an ordered list of days with a conventional line-wrap of 7 days.

Comment: ps, you can shorten `document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0)` to `document.body`.

Comment: also, you can't insert content in a `tr`. `<table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></table>` Is a 1-row, 2-column table with values `A` and `B`.

Comment: hmm then  `code currentDate = date.insertCell(timestamp)
          table.appendChild(currentDate);`